# How to add a unique id to a child element in an XSD file?

Tags: xsd

I cannot figure out how to create my XSD file to have a unique id to the child element. It works fine for the root element, but copying this code and changing the values does not work, so I assume I am doing something wrong. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flights
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">

    <flight flightid="1">
        <plane planeid="1">Airbus A380-861</plane>
    </flight>

</flights>
```

Here is the XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="flights">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="flight" 
                            type="flighttype" 
                            minOccurs='1' 
                            maxOccurs='unbounded' />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="flightidisunique">
            <xs:selector xpath="flight"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@flightid"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="flighttype">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="plane" 
                        type="planetype" 
                        minOccurs='1' 
                        maxOccurs='unbounded' />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:unique name="planeidisunique">
            <xs:selector xpath="plane"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@planeid"/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:attribute name="flightid" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="planetype">
        <xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="planeid" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

What is the correct way to create a valid Schema for the XML I have posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following schema makes sure that `flightid` is unique amongst all `flight` elements and that `planeid` is unique amongst all `plane` elements within the same `flight` element:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:element name="flights">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="flight" type="flighttype" minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded'>
          <xs:unique name="planeidisunique">
            <xs:selector xpath="plane"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@planeid"/>
          </xs:unique>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="flightidisunique">
      <xs:selector xpath="flight"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@flightid"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="flighttype">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="plane" type="planetype" minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="flightid" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="planetype" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="planeid" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

This variation of the schema makes `planeid` unique amongst ALL `plane` elements:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:element name="flights">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="flight" type="flighttype" minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded'>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="flightidisunique">
      <xs:selector xpath="flight"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@flightid"/>
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="planeidisunique">
      <xs:selector xpath="flight/plane"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@planeid"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="flighttype">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="plane" type="planetype" minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="flightid" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="planetype" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="planeid" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: This is amazing, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for! I also needed to know the difference between making plane unique globally, or just inside flight! Thanks a lot for this!!!

Answer (score 2):

Imagining you want a xml like this:

```
<flights xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">

    <flight flightid="f1">
        <plane planeid="f1p1">Airbus A380-861</plane>
        <plane planeid="f1p2">Airbus A380-861</plane>
        <plane planeid="f1p3">Airbus A380-861</plane>
        <plane planeid="f1p4">Airbus A380-861</plane>
    </flight>

    <flight flightid="f2">
        <plane planeid="f2p1">Airbus A380-862</plane>
    </flight>
</flights>
```

You will need a schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="flights">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="flight" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="flight">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="plane" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="flightid" use="required" type="xs:ID"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="plane">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:attribute name="planeid" use="required" type="xs:ID"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

For you ids to be unique those attributes will need to of type **"xs:ID"** and a xs:ID is a NCName meaning it's a name not a number eg:one or a1.
Also added maxOccurs="unbounded" to nodes **flight** and **plane**

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: Declaring an attribute of type `xs:ID` is not enough to constrain its values to be unique.

Comment: @MiMo, I think you must be thinking of something else.  Declaring an attribute as being of type xs:ID certainly constrains its values to be unique within the set of xs:ID values within the document (or within the validation root).  That's somewhat stronger than the OP asked for, but it's not weaker.